How check browser support in CSS for @view-transition navigation: auto?
Google Chrome 126 is introducing cross-document view transitions in CSS (source) with
@view-transition {
    navigation: auto;
}

Now I would like to check the support of the user's browser with:
@supports (navigation: auto) {
    --available: true;
}

But testing in Chrome v126 the @supports is not triggered, please see this codepen as an example: https://codepen.io/olvrschwrz/pen/YzoqYYG
I would expect that the @supports (navigation: auto) is evaluated as true in Chrome v126 and onwards.
One could work around and use @supports with selectors ::-view-transition-old(root) and ::view-transition-new(root) but this would not explicitly check on cross-document view transition.

Not sure this can be tested (other than actually trying it) but just because Chrome now has it does not mean @supports has been extended yet to include it. 2c

FYI doesn't work in Edge either which is supposed to be compatible.

@Paulie_D I agree with you, but the Chromium/Chrome team should ensure that other features are also taken into account when shipping new features.

It does seem that @supports does not (as yet) include this property. Presumably this will be added later - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/bGPpaZj That said, if it's not supported how would it matter? ☺ The code would not take effect and no-one would be the wiser. If it is supported and works, it's just a nice effect... the code isn't any less, it just not used where not supported.

I can't find a list of what is supported by, ahem, @supports but if anyone can find them it would be useful.

Thank you for your research, the @view-transition with navigation: auto works in Chrome v126. It just that there is no CSS-way to check/see the support of the cross-document view transition even though the Chrome supports it.

You might like to add that as an answer then you can mark it as accepted for everyone's future use.

navigation is not a property but a descriptor, which cannot be tested with @supports at the moment. The CSSWG recently resolved on defining at-rule(@rule, descriptor: value) to address this need. For example, @supports at-rule(@view-transition, navigation: auto) {}.
As a workaround, you can extract the related CSS in its own file and load it with this <script> in the <head> of your document:
<script>
    function supportsAtRule(rule) {
        const sheet = new CSSStyleSheet()
        sheet.replaceSync(rule)
        return sheet.cssRules[0]?.cssText === rule
    }
    if (supportsAtRule('@view-transition { navigation: auto; }')) {
        const link = document.createElement('link')
        link.rel = "stylesheet"
        link.href = 'view-transitions.css'
        document.head.appendChild(link)
    }
</script>

